# How to use microsoft media foundation to detect which process uses camera?

Tags: c++, ms-media-foundation

I am new to msmf. Can you give me some tutorial, how to use IMFSensorActivityReport interface to tell me which process is using my webcam? There is a method GetProcessActivity which I assume does that or possibly other IMFSensorActivity stuff but I have no clue how to use it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nn-mfidl-imfsensoractivityreport

Answer (score 1):

I never use it, but i will start here :

[MFCreateSensorActivityMonitor function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-mfcreatesensoractivitymonitor)

You must implement [IMFSensorActivitiesReportCallback interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nn-mfidl-imfsensoractivitiesreportcallback).

When [IMFSensorActivitiesReportCallback::OnActivitiesReport method](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nf-mfidl-imfsensoractivitiesreportcallback-onactivitiesreport) will be raised by the media pipeline, you will receive a pointer to the IMFSensorActivityReport.

You normally need to call CoInitializeEx and MFStartup before.

If you want to see how to use some IMFCallback in an application, check this example :
[IMFSinkWriterCallback](https://github.com/mofo7777/Stackoverflow/tree/master/IMFSinkWriterCallback)
This is for IMFSinkWriterCallback, but the same can be applied to  IMFSensorActivitiesReportCallback.

**EDIT**

More code here : [IMFSensorActivityMonitor interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/mfidl/nn-mfidl-imfsensoractivitymonitor)